# Cannot add item to inventory (Bukkit/Spigot)

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit, inventory

I have some problems with my kits plugin for Bukkit and Spigot.
When I use the command /kits only an empty inventory opens.
Here's my code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i<main.cfg.getConfigurationSection("kits").getKeys(false).size();i++) {
            String s = (String) main.cfg.getConfigurationSection("kits").getKeys(false).toArray()[i];
            ItemStack is = new ItemStack(Material.valueOf(main.cfg.getString("kits." + s + ".mat")));
            ItemMeta im = is.getItemMeta();
            im.setDisplayName(s);
            is.setItemMeta(im);
            cont.add(is);
        }
```

the item stack is valid, but when I do kits.add (is) the item doesn't get added to the inventory.

- I have created the inventory kits with `Bukkit.createInventory(null,size,"Kits");` and it shows up correctly
- After I have added all items, I open up the inventory with `((Player)sender).openInventory(kits);`

You see `cont.add(is)` in the code, because I've tried to make a list of ItemStack (cont) and then in another for loop add all items to the inventory, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. It was because I calculated the size of the inventory depending on how many kits there are. Today I wondered why I had 3 lines in the inventory and just 1 kit. that should only make 1 line. then I set it to 54 items so 6 lines as inventory size and it worked! **Solution: make sure that you're creating at least 3 lines in your inventory, then it should work.**

Answer (score 0):

The only think of is maybe "main.cfg.getConfigurationSection("kits").getKeys(false).size()" is returning 0, causing the code in the for loop to never execute. Maybe you could add "sender.sendMessage("The for loop is running");" inside the for loop just to verify that it is in fact running.

Comment: I'm sure It is running, because I put a sysout into the loop to print the data of the itemStack. and it has put out the data.

Comment: "Hm, that's a tricky one... – Bill Ray 13 hours ago " Yes, that's right, With all my other plugins the GUI over inventories works perfect, but I made everything exactly like in this one.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't add, it's addItem :)

```
cont.addItem(is);
```

Comment: cont is not a Inventory It's a List<ItemStack> (read my edit)

Comment: Oh, my bad. That really is odd.